# Spring custom validation

Tags: spring

I am learning Spring for my application and currently I am using Spring Validator interface to for my validation. I was wondering if I could write something like a custom xml with all my validation rules which I can then use Spring to read and validate.

Something along the lines of

```
<rules>

    <rule> 
           <id="name" name="rule1" mandatory="yes" bean="foo.com.name" />
           <status name="rule1" type="error" />
    </rule>

    <rule> 
           <id="age" name="rule2" mandatory="no" bean="foo.com.age" />
           <status name="rule2" type="warning" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
```

Can anyone please point to me in the right direction.

I see value in this because then I can have all my validation in one xml and can organize my validations  easily. Further more I can even reuse this xml.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSR-303 support XML descriptors and Spring can expose the `ValidationFactory` through Spring `Validator` interface by the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`.

You may be interested that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen or considered OVal for your validation? [About OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/)

I've used this for a large collection of beans, all extend a common base bean class that implements a validate method that uses the OVal validator. Each bean has its fields/methods annotated as per it's unique requirements. Works pretty well, I like the fact that the validation is clearly visible on the bean, not hidden away in a bespoke format or framework, plus the error messages for failures are well detailled too.